# return NA via RCpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Newbie RCpp question here: how can I make a NumericVector return `NA` to R?  For example, suppose I have a RCpp code that assigns `NA` to the first element of a vector.

```
// [[RCpp::export]]
NumericVector myFunc(NumericVector x) {
   NumericVector y=clone(x);
   y[0]=NA; // <----- what's the right expression here?
   return y;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The canonical way to get the correct `NA` for a given vector type (`NumericVector`, `IntegerVector`, ...)  is to use the static `get_na` method. Something like:

```
y[0] = NumericVector::get_na() ;
```

FWIW, your code works as is with `Rcpp11`, which knows how to convert from the static `Na_Proxy`  instance `NA` into the correct missing value for the target type.

Comment: And BTW, it would be trivial to have the same behavior in Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. It might be a shorter way of writing: `NumericVector y=no_init(n); for (int i=0;i<n;i++) { y[i]=NA_REAL;}`, e.g. `y=NumericVector::get_na()`.

Comment: `get_na` gives you a single value. You can use `NumericVector y = rep( NumericVector::get_na(), n )` or `NumericVector y(n, NumericVector::get_na() ) ;` for example if you want a vector of NA of  size `n`.

Answer (score 7):

Please at least try to grep through the large corpus of examples provided by our regression tests:

```
edd@max:~$ cd  /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/unitTests/cpp/
edd@max:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/unitTests/cpp$ grep NA *cpp | tail -5
support.cpp:           Rf_pentagamma( NA_REAL) ,
support.cpp:           expm1( NA_REAL ),
support.cpp:           log1p( NA_REAL ),
support.cpp:           Rcpp::internal::factorial( NA_REAL ),
support.cpp:           Rcpp::internal::lfactorial( NA_REAL )
edd@max:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/unitTests/cpp$
```

Moreover, this is actually a C question for R and answered in the Writing R Extensions manual.

You could also have found a good example in [this Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/working-with-missing-values/) as well as others; there is a search function right at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).