# Return NA from Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to return NA via Rcpp. I do not understand why `get_na()` doesn't work here as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23745470/6484844)?

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector temp1() {
   return NumericVector::get_na();
 }')
> temp1()
Error in temp1() : negative length vectors are not allowed
```

If I try `create()` it works.

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector temp2() {
    return NumericVector::create(NA_REAL);
  }')
> temp2()
  NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector temp1() {
  NumericVector y(1);
  y[0] = NumericVector::get_na();
  return y;
}')

temp1()
#R> [1] NA
```

if you want to use `NumericVector::get_na()`. Note that [this member function](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/f3c5a34e06e774532227470b01c63a8f08ce4313/inst/include/Rcpp/traits/get_na.h#L38-L39) simply returns `NA_REAL` which is why you presuambly get the error with `NumericVector`'s constructor with:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector temp1() {
   return NumericVector::get_na();
 }')
```

You can equally well use `NumericVector::create` as you suggest. You can also do:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('NumericVector temp2() {
  return NumericVector(1, NA_REAL);
}')
```

or

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('double temp3() {
  return NA_REAL;
}')
```

> Return NA from Rcpp

If you are dealing with other types of vectors then the `NumericVector` then the `get_na` function can be very useful. Here is an example where we return NA but with different types depending on the input.

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '
  #include "Rcpp.h"
  using namespace Rcpp;
  
  template<int T>
  Vector<T> get_na_genric(){
    return Vector<T>(1, Vector<T>::get_na());
  }
  
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  SEXP get_nan_vec(SEXP x) {
    switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
      case INTSXP : return get_na_genric<INTSXP >();
      case LGLSXP : return get_na_genric<LGLSXP >();
      case REALSXP: return get_na_genric<REALSXP>();
      case STRSXP : return get_na_genric<STRSXP >();
      case VECSXP : return get_na_genric<VECSXP >();
      stop("type not implemented");
    }
    
    return get_na_genric<REALSXP>();
  }')

for(x in list(integer(), logical(), numeric(), character(), 
              list())){
  out <- get_nan_vec(x)
  cat("got:\n")
  print(out)
  cat("with type ", typeof(out), "\n")
}
#R> got:
#R> [1] NA
#R> with type  integer 
#R> got:
#R> [1] NA
#R> with type  logical 
#R> got:
#R> [1] NA
#R> with type  double 
#R> got:
#R> [1] NA
#R> with type  character 
#R> got:
#R> [[1]]
#R> NULL
#R> 
#R> with type  list
```

Comment: Nice answer. One important issue is that a `NA` _is_ a value so you have to allocate as the answers shows, and as the original `create()` approach by OP did too.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.